# What is the best way to get the size of text in the tag when parsing HTML+CSS with python?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping HTML pages of live websites using python and beautifulsoup4. I want to be able get the size of the text of any html tag. I tried to use cssutils to parse the CSS and find font-size param but real life CSS is pretty complicated like this

```
.some_div_class a span {font-size: 20px}
```

So I can find all tags that correspond to this selector using bs.select(selector) but trying every selector in stylesheet will take way too much time. So how is it possible to find font-size for any tag efficiently? Browsers do it pretty fast, so it shouldn't be impossible.
I don't want to use headless browser.

Comment: This might be a duplicate request. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297576/parse-css-in-python on solution to parse css using python. The solution is present and accepted by the community.

Comment: Did the stackoverflow reference help?

Answer (score 0):

To find the font size of the text efficiently:

1. create 2 dictionaries of all classes and their associated properties (one for external other for in page styles (in the `style` tag))
2. get the element to find font size
3. check if inline style present
4. if inline style not present search in page then check external stylesheet